# vTiger: read only field shown on edit view

Tags: javascript, php, module, vtiger

I have created a custom module and I have a number field which I want to make read only.

The problem I have is if i set the field to read only in the database by changing the display type to 2, it doesn't show on the edit view but does make the field read only in detail view.

I have created a a view in `\layouts\v7\modules\<CUSTOMODULE>\uitypes` which makes adds the `readonly` attribute to my specific field. This only works if the display type is set to 1.

Is there a way to keep my edit view so i can see the readonly field with it's value but also make the field readonly in detail view?

I did think about using javascript to return false on the edit button

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this for anybody else facing the same problem

Here is what I did.

1. Create a new folder in `vtiger_root\layouts\v7\modules\ModuleName` (will either be `v7` or `vlayout` depending what version of vTiger)
2. Create a new folder in the new folder called `vtiger_root\layouts\v7\modules\ModuleName\uitypes`
3. Copy from `vtiger_root\layouts\v7\modules\Vtiger\uitypes`, the field type tpl file into folder created in step 2 (in my case I copied the `Number.tpl` file)
4. Add the following code just before the closing `/>` replacing 'yourfield' with the field name

   ```
   {if $FIELD_MODEL->getFieldName() eq 'yourfield'}
       readonly="true"
   {/if}
   ```
5. Copy from `vtiger_root\layouts\v7\modules\Vtiger`, files `DetailViewBlockView.tpl` and `DetailViewFullContents.tpl` and place them in your new module folder created in step 1
6. In the `DetailViewFullContents.tpl` file look for the line containing

   ```
   {if $IS_AJAX_ENABLED && $FIELD_MODEL->isEditable() eq 'true' && $FIELD_MODEL->isAjaxEditable() eq 'true'}
   ```

   and replace it with

   ```
   {if $IS_AJAX_ENABLED && $FIELD_MODEL->isEditable() eq 'true' && $FIELD_MODEL->isAjaxEditable() eq 'true' && $FIELD_MODEL->getFieldName() neq 'yourfield'}
   ```